# How to send multiple same name input fields value via ajax post method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[image]

I have two same name multiple input fields. I want to send all fields value from another page using jquery ajax post method but i am not getting all rows input fields value. Please review my code.

Javascript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getValue()
{
    $.post("paidamt.php",
    {
      paidamt : $('#paidamt').val(),
      uid : $('#uid').val()
    },
      function( data){
        /*alert(data);*/
        $("#divShow").html(data);
    });  
 }
</script>
```

Html Code

```
<div>
<form method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Paid Amount</th>
<th>Check</th>
</tr>
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbldemo`");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $result['pname']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="paidamt[]" id="paidamt"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="uid[]" id="uid" 
value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php }
?>
</table><br>
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" 
onclick="getValue(1)" value="Save Amt.">
</form>
</div>
<div id="divShow">
</div>
```

Comment: ideally there should not be multiple controls with same ID in a form. You can use name instead of id. Like - $('input[name="paidamt"]').

Answer (score 1):

Try this  one

```
var paidamt = $("input[name=paidamt]").map(function(){
return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");

var uid = $("input[name=uid]").map(function(){
return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");


$.ajax(
{
type: "POST",
url: 'paidamt.php',
data:
{
    paidamt:paidamt,
    uid:uid
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have given the `input` elements the same `id` which is repeated in the loop. This will end up in your HTML being invalid, you should change the `id` to `class`:

```html
<form method="post">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Paid Amount</th>
            <th>Check</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbldemo`");
            while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $result['pname']; ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="paidamt[]" class="paidamt"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="uid[]" class="uid" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }
        ?>
    </table><br>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Save Amt.</button>
</form>
```

To actually send the input values in the AJAX request you can simply `serialize()` the containing form when the form is submit:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "paidamt.php", 
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#divShow").html(data);
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add class instead of id, since identically class can be repeated but id should not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue()
{
    var paidamtval = [];
    $('#paidamt').each(function(){
       paidamtval.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.post("paidamt.php",
    {
      paidamt : paidamtval,
      uid : $('#uid').val()
    },
      function( data){
        /*alert(data);*/
        $("#divShow").html(data);
    });  
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you will have many of these, id - needs to be unique, which in your case isn't, so remove "id="paidamt"

```
    <td><input type="text" name="paidamt[]" id="paidamt"></td>
```

That's your first mistake. And secondly don't use $.post, to submit this form. Either remove AJAX submit, or bind form using something like [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Comment: Just found it was already suggested on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form

Answer (score 0):

You try this code

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){

 jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "paidamt.php",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,       
            cache: false,             
            processData:false,    
            success: function(html){
               try{ 
                 $("#divShow").html(data);
                 }catch (e){
                 alert(JSON.stringify(e));
                 }
             },
                 error : function(e){alert("error "+JSON.stringify(e)); }
        });
        });


        });
```

in you paidamt.php file

```
$paidamt=$_POST['paidamt'];// its can array values
print_r($paidamt);// result display
```

Comment: getting error "TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement."